# How to create labels dynamically in PyQt5

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5

I am creating a basic GUI application which implements [D'hontds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D%27Hondt_method) method using PyQt5, and having trouble creating `Qlbales` dynamically i.e. I want to display the results in these labels, and the number of labels is based on the number of inputs by the user so it varies. I could create the maximum number and then use just the ones I need, but I am sure there are neater and more effective solutions.

I have tried with `exec` and `eval` (I know it is poor approach), but nevertheless I have not succeeded. I think `eval` fails to read element from the list somehow, not sure. Here is what I've tried (`i+5` because I have 4 more labels) :

```
def set_result_labels(self):

        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(15)
        for i in range(len(self.text_parties_names)):
            exec(f"self.label_{i+5} = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)")
            eval(f"self.label_{i+5}.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(640, {(i+5)*40}, 50, 50))")
            eval(f"self.label_{i+5}.setFont(font)")
            eval(f"self.label_{i+5}.setText(self.text_parties_names[i])")
```

and `self.text_partirs_names` is list with the names from `textEdits` (user input):

```
def get_parties_names(self):
        for text_edit in self.text_edit_parties_list:
            if text_edit.toPlainText():
                self.text_parties_names.append(text_edit.toPlainText())
```

Comment: don't use eval or exec, instead use setattr: `label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget) label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(640, (i+5)*40, 50, 50)) ... setattr(self, f"label_{i+5}", label)`

Comment: Yeah, this is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you